# Run scheduletask after some time interval once it's created

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a schedule task which will run after some second once it is created.

I am trying with below but looks like i am doing the schedule trigger incorrectly.

Any help or thoughts ?

```
$time = Get-Date -Format T
ipmo ScheduledTasks 
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -command "& {stop-process -processname "notepad*"}"' 
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $time -RandomDelay (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 7)
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "My Task" -Description "Task to disable service"
```

Comment: Is your intention to run the task once?  At a random delay after it's created?

Comment: yes... i want to run only once after the task is created.. and task should run after 7 seconds after the creation

Comment: What's the application of doing so?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Lets say i have job running in one system which has 1)presteps 2)mycustomjob  3) poststep ..in last step my job i will create a schedule task which will schedule it to run after some seconds... this will give time to complete the poststep..... as after some seconds once post step is done.. my schedule task will start its work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet will create the scheduled task to run 7 seconds after execution.

```
$Params = @{
  Action = (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell' -Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Stop-Process -Name notepad*"')
  Trigger = (New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).AddSeconds(7))
  TaskName = 'My Task'
  Description = 'Task to disable service'
}
Register-ScheduledTask @Params
```

Comment: Thank you, only updating  "-Once -At (Get-Date).AddSeconds(7))" to my code works fine.

Comment: Please add ')' to -Action statement to resolve the error

Answer (score 0):

The New-ScheduledTaskTrigger cmdlet has an irrational limitation of not supporting the -Daily option and the Repetition options at the same time.  But it turns out you can override the Repetition element of the resulting PowerShell object as follows.

Essentially, you create the trigger object twice.  The first time, specify the -Once flag with your repetition options.  Then, save off the Repetition element of the resulting trigger in a variable.  Then, create a second trigger object with the -Daily option.  Finally, overwrite the second trigger's Repetition element with the saved Repetition element from the first trigger.

```
# Construct the first trigger with a 30 minute repetition interval
$interval = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 30
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval $interval

# Save off the repetition element of the resulting trigger object
$repetition=$trigger.Repetition

# Recreate the trigger with the -Daily option, specifying a start TOD
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 12am

# Finally, overwrite the Repetition element with the saved repetition from earlier.
$trigger.Repetition=$repetition

# Now you can specify the final trigger object as your daily, recurring trigger.
# This worked in Windows 10 and Windows 11.
```